# How to wrap an anonymous enum in Cython and give it a name?

Tags: python, enums, cython

I'm wrapping some C++ code with Cython and have some issues with an anonymous enum nested in two namespaces.

Example definition from `some_header.hpp`:

```
namespace A {
    namespace B {
        enum {
            X = 0,
            Y = 1,
            Z = 2
        };
    }
}
```

My `.pxd` file for the above header file:

```
cdef extern from 'some_header.hpp' namespace 'A::B':
    cdef enum:
        CX 'A::B::X'    \
        CY 'A::B::Y'     > Can this be simplified somehow?
        CZ 'A::B::Z'    /
```

My `.pyx` wrapper module:

```
class B(IntEnum):
    X = CX    \
    Y = CY     > CX, CY and CZ are global in my .pyx module
    Z = CZ    /
```

I can use `CX`, `CY` and `CZ` in my `.pyx` file as you can see above, but would be great if I could do something like `CB.X`, `CB.Y` and `CB.Z`, ie. `CX/CY/CZ` wouldn't be global in my module.

Also can the extended namespace `'A::B::X'` in `.pxd` be simplified or dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to have a very small `pxd` file that declares only this enum inside its namespaces.  That way the enum has a simple namespace in the rest of your Cython code.  I'm able to get this to compile / work on OS X:

The interfacing `.pxd` file:

```
# a.pxd
cdef extern from "some_header.cpp" namespace "A::B":
    cdef enum:
        X
        Y
        Z
```

And demo code

```
cimport a

cpdef foobar():
    return a.X, a.Y, a.Z # enum values are namespaced inside `a`
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't experimented with Cython's C++ support myself but have you tried simply giving it a name to the enum, pretty sure Cython doesn't care whether the referenced enum is anonymous or not. These enum values will still be in the global scope regardless.

Also you could try defining those enums with Cython's `cpdef` and save some typing, maybe something like:

```
cdef extern from 'some_header.hpp' namespace 'A::B':
    cpdef enum B:
        X
        Y
        Z
```

Then again, this is accounting only for C-level Cython support so I'm not pretty sure if this exactly works with C++ code.

Comment: Cython accepts this syntax, but unfortunately MSVC throws the error `C2039: 'B': is not a member of 'A::B'`.

Comment: @PythonFanboy Yeah I just confirmed myself that Cython does indeed relies on the name definition of an enum. This doesn't seem to be a problem in C because of, I assume, the lack of namespaces in the language. Then I guess you don't have much more alternatives than what you already have.

Comment: Btw, I just realized that your main concern seems to be that these enums end up on the global scope of your Cython wrapper. This is definitely intended behavior in favor of the interface pattern that Cython "provides". In other words, you should wrap C/C++ headers in a differently named Cython definition file and `cimport` from it. You could read http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications and maybe http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html

Comment: Try `cpdef enum B "A::B": ...`